# Как перетащить несколько коммитов в другую ветку в git?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-cherry-pick

**Дано:** существуют две ветки, ветка prod в которой то что лежит на боевом сервере и ветка develop из которой выкатывается на тестовый. Они разумеется во многом похожи но содержат множество принципиально разных фичей.
В один прекрасный день возникает необходимость запилить тяжелую фичу прямо от прода. Фича запиливается. Остается вопрос - как перетащить ее в ветку девелоп, чтобы при этом не было нужно мержить всех предков этой фичи.
Смотри картинку:
**Случай А:** Я хочу перетащить коммиты E и F не перетаскивая коммиты A и B. Как?
**Случай B:** этот и дальше на практике мне пока не нужны (и рисовать было лень) но любопытно: пусть F - это некоторое множество последовательных коммитов не оформленных в отдельную ветку (т.е. не существует ветки содержащей в себе коммиты F и только их) Я хочу перетащить коммиты F, но не хочу коммит(ы) E. Как?
**Случай C:**, хочу перетащить всю ветку фичи кроме одного-трех коммитов, которые находятся где-нибудь в середине ветки и не являются последовательными
**Случай D:**, Это случай А плюс добавим что ветку от прода надо сохранить.
**E:** возможно ли при этом задать какое-нибудь автоматическое разрешение конфликтов в сторону (девелопа)/(ветки с фичей)  если они будут

Пока я нашел cherry-pick но перетаскивать ветку по одному коммиту - то еще извращение и наверняка есть человеческий способ. Правильно ли я понимаю что мне нужно копать куда-то в сторону rebase?

[image]

Comment: *Случай Б* - нельзя сделать коммиты, которые не будут оформлены в ветку. Любой коммит пренадлежит какой то ветке.

Comment: @KoVadim, поправил описание чтобы было понятнее. Понятно что любая последовательность коммитов - это ветка некоторого дерева. Я имею в виду именованную ветку, или эти сущности не отличаются физически?

Comment: @fori1ton, ок, спасибо. А правильно ли решать такую задачу именно с помощью cherry-pick?

Comment: нет в git просто ветки. Любая ветка имеет имя. В принципе можно удалить ветку (коммиты остануться) тогда они не будут как бы пренадлежат ни одной ветке. Но как в эту анонимную ветку коммитить... И gc может легко почистить подобную "ветку". Но это уже отдельное мастерство в git.

Comment: Сделайте кто-нибудь комментарий fori1ton ответом, чтобы я его мог принять

Comment: @Volt done

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[@Volt](/users/17812/volt), `git cherry-pick` позволяет переносить несколько коммитов сразу. Для этого нужно задать, например, диапазон коммитов: `git cherry-pick F..E`. Подробнее о задании диапазонов коммитов читейте здесь: http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html

Answer (score 6):

Слегка поразбирался сам:
Кроме массового черри-пика часть задач можно решить с помощью

```
git rebase -i --onto develop prod feature
```

Флаг `-i` позволяет решать какие коммиты оставить, какие перетаскивать из этого множества, кому изменить сообщения. Гит откроет свой редактор (по умолчанию vim) и предложит назначить каждому коммиту из ветки feature соответствующий флаг (оставить, убрать, слить с предыдущим) и изменить сообщения если нужно.
Как я понимаю этот механизм применяется также для приведения истории коммитов в порядок.

Способа автоматически разрешать конфликты пока не нашел.

Comment: @Volt, rebase не делает из нескольких коммитов один, насколько знаю. Он просто перетаскивает дельту каждого "наверх", в конец ветки.

Comment: > Гит откроет свой редактор (vim)

это просто отлично:) вим - это отдельный редактор, а не "свой".

> Способа автоматически разрешать конфликты пока не нашел.

это иногда просто физически невозможно.

Comment: @Fike, с помощью rebase -i и выставления флагов fixup и squash при интерактивном мерже можно сделать из нескольких коммитов меньше с тем же содержимым. Схлопнуть их в один например.

Comment: @KoVadim, ага я знаю) Увы, я практически не работал с ним, он весьма неинтуитивен поэтому воспринимается как дополнительное препятствие...

Понятно что иногда физически невозможно разрешить вот прям все, но хотелось бы научиться автоматически разрешать в сторону указанной ветки все что возможно. И я слышал что такая возможность где-то есть...

Answer (score 5):

Если вы работаете в IntelliJ IDEA, то в консоли на закладке Version Control можно просматривать логи. На вкладке логов можно для одного из коммитов выполнить Cherry-Pick.
Cherry-Pick – это способ забрать в текущую выбранную ветку отдельный коммит из другой ветки, не затрагивая остальных коммитов. После чего можно сделать Commit and Push в удалённый репозиторий.