# Как переместить комиты с одной ветки в другую?

Tags: git, git-commit, git-branch

Случайно делал комиты не в той ветке, что нужно.
В результате накопилось 10 комитов в ветке, которая никак не относится к нужной!
Как можно переместить комиты с одной ветки в другую ?

Использовал команду:

```
git cherry-pick
```

Но мне бросает ошибку:

```
error: Коммит a17d9471217e650f54dec04d4da1c9520e20e64e — это коммит-слияние, но опция -m не указана.
fatal: сбой при отборе лучшего
```

**Как это сделать правильно ?**

Comment: Вам нужна команда git rebase, но ее стоит использовать аккуратно.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/318251/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D0%B2-git

Comment: Попробуйте прочитать документацию по git cherry-pick, и напишите, устраивает ли вас опция -m и если нет, то почему?