# Как сделать ребейз с удалением уже смерженных коммитов?

Tags: git

Есть мастер и мои 2 ветки:

```
A -> B -> C                <- master
     |
     -> D' -> E'           <- my 1
              |
              F'' -> G''   <- my 2
```

Мастер замержил себе `my 1`, но не `my 2`:

```
A -> B -> C -> D -> E      <- master
     |
     -> D' -> E'           <- my 1
              |
              F'' -> G''   <- my 2
```

Можно ли теперь **1 командой** сделать ребейз `my 2` на мастер так, чтобы в `my 2` были `D` и `E`, а не `D'` и `E'`?

Если просто сделать ребейз, то получаю в `my 2` дублирующиеся коммиты `D -> E -> D' -> E' -> F'' -> G''`. Можно после ребейза удалить лишние, конечно, но хотелось бы 1 командой.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как перетащить несколько коммитов в другую ветку в git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/318251/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b2-git)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin не понял, как это применить. Сделать вместо ребейза `cherry-pick`? И за счёт чего удалятся лишние коммиты?

Comment: да там и про rebase написано. и, да, «лишние» коммиты никак не удаляются из репозитория, кроме как явно удалить ссылки на них и произвести garbage collection.

Comment: `git rebase --onto master my1`, если я правильно понял чехарду с буковками и `E' === B'`

Comment: В заголовке и в вопросе упоминаются некоторые смердженные коммиты, однако на диаграмме таковых нема. Неясно, чем у тут D' E' отличаются от D и E. Если ничем, то тут будет работать обычный rebase на С.